# windows ctrl + c signals not firing

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi, console-application

I'm working on an application that launches powershell scripts to setup and launch service processes (not formal windows services). I want to be able to send <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> signals to these powershell processes and their child processes to cleanly shut them down.

When I create the powershell process I set `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` which implicitly calls `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL,TRUE)` which effectively turns off <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> for the created process and its children. I can't use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>break</kbd> because that puts powershell into debug mode. So in the powershell process I launch, I call `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL,FALSE)` to turn <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> back on and have my application then calls `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` to send <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> events to powershell's process group when I want to stop that process tree. This works perfectly but with one major flaw.

If I manuall type ctrl+c in the console where my application is running, my application intercepts the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and then calls `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` for each powershell process. This seems to work well but ONLY the first time.

After my application exits it seems <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is now turned off for any program i run in that console. If I run `PING` or my own application, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> does nothing and I'm unsure how to debug further.

Interestingly, I sometimes see handles in process explorer to the dead powershell processes in conhost.exe. If I close those handles in process explorer, SOMETIMES <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> comes back. So I suspect some handle leakage but this observation is not consistent and I am careful to free my process handles in my application.

Any thoughts on what may be causing my console's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> signals to be swallowed?

Comment: Everything after `UPDATE` should be cut out and posted as an answer. Yes, you are allowed to answer your own questions; no, we will not think less of you for doing so; no, answers should *not* be embedded in questions.

Comment: That's fair @JeroenMostert. I guess it wasn't really the answer I wanted to hear but may likely be the best answer I'm going to get :)

Comment: You're free not to accept your own answer if you don't consider it satisfying. :-) Bounties are another way to attract attention.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that firing `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` after a user invoked <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is what puts the shell into this strange state. When the user enters <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> there is really no need for my application to call `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` because the GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent broadcasts to every process in the console. Unfortunately having my app forego `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` when it intercepts <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is easier said than done but not impossible.

Its unsettling that I have found no documentation or information stating that firing `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` after a typed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> has this odd effect but perhaps this post will help someone else.

If anyone has insights into more detail on why this state gets triggered or tips on other ways to avoid it and making the shell more resilient to `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`, please post another answer here.